# Should redundant information be added to a DB to ensure that any product changes don't affect the output of purchase orders

Tags: database

I'm trying to figure out how best to layout my database for storing records of purchases, and later on having the possibility or displaying purchases accurately. Thus far I have this:

**Products**

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+
|  item_id  |  item_name  |  price  |  discount  |
+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+
|  1        |  Product 1  |  5.00   |  3.50      |
|  2        |  Product 2  |  14.99  |  12.00     |
|  3        |  Product 3  |  29.99  |  0         |
+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+
```

**Orders:**

```
+------------+-----------+--------------+
|  order_id  |  user_id  |  order_date  |
+------------+-----------+--------------+
|  1         |  1        |  2015-08-02  |
|  2         |  2        |  2015-08-30  |
|  3         |  3        |  2015-09-01  |
|  4         |  2        |  2015-09-03  |
+------------+-----------+--------------+

+---------+------------+-----------+-------+
|  oi_id  |  order_id  |  item_id  |  qte  |
+---------+------------+-----------+-------+
|  1      |  1         |  1        |  5    |
|  2      |  1         |  2        |  2    |
|  3      |  2         |  1        |  1    |
|  4      |  2         |  2        |  6    |
|  5      |  3         |  2        |  1    |
|  6      |  4         |  3        |  3    |
+---------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

My main concern thus far are;

1. What if a product detail is change (ie. item_name, price, discount, etc)
2. What is a product is deleted entirely

If either of those use-cases occurs, any information I try to re-display/print out will no longer have the correct information. The easy solution that comes to mind would be to have redundant data, where the order item table includes a copy of all of the columns that are important enough to keep (name, price, discount, etc). However, I have always been told to avoid redundancies as much as possible.

Comment: Keep track of history, what was the product price at what moment? Don't delete products, (you can't you have a foreign key to it) but mark them as deleted.

Comment: @EdwinStoteler As much as I'd love to say no item will ever be deleted or majorly modified, truth is this build is quite likely going to be added/reused for clients, and I can't account for their actions.

Comment: Protect them from their own mistakes. For example, create a instead of delete trigger on products that marks the product as deleted. Or handle the logic in the application DAL. For new clients you might want to deliver a empty database anyway. Saving the information also in the order is a solution, but not a nice one.

Comment: Modifying things so that items are marked as "delete" rather than be deleted isn't a big issue. However, I have had clients that instead of creating new items, have opened up existing items and completely changed them to be new items. Hence my issue about items being modified. It's not just small changes I'm afraid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest for this instance it can be better to have redundant data in orderdetails table, so that in will not cause any false data display.

Ideally you should not delete any product physically instead of that you can have another column may as "IsDeleted" and use this to identify whether it is deleted item or not.

If in case you want to avoid redundancy then you need implement some logic like.
You can have separate ProductPrice table where there will price, starttime,endtime columns and its primary key will foregin key in OrderDetails table.